# Найти число, из которого можно вычислить целый корень

Tags: python

Не могу понять, что не так. Программа должна получить с консоли натуральное число `n` и найти число, следующее за `n`, которое является полным квадратом.

```
x = int(input())

while True:
   if type(x**0.5) == int:
      print(x)
      break
   x += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно

```
def nextSquare(N): 

    nextN = math.floor(math.sqrt(N)) + 1

    return nextN * nextN 

print(nextSquare(11))
```

Comment: @extrn Блин, точно... следующее же...

Answer (score 0):

Вот что неправильно:

```
type(x**0.5) == int
```

`type(x**0.5)` всегда `float`, независимо от `х`.